# How to get data for all profiles of 'ProfileSessionSettings' metadata object in single API call?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api

I want to fetch '**ProfileSessionSettings**' for all applicable profiles in the **single API call**.

I can do this operation for a single profile using the following request body, but am unable to do it for **all profiles in a single call**.

**Request body**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <SessionHeader>
            <sessionId> </sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
          <readMetadata>
            <type>ProfilePasswordPolicy</type>
            <fullName>Custom_Platform_User_profilePasswordPolicy1643607639467</fullName>
          </readMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

`readMetadata` can be used to retrieve upto 10 components. Since `ProfilePasswordPolicy` and `ProfileSessionSetting` supports wildcard retrieve, you could retrieve all of them using following package.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfileSessionSetting</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ProfilePasswordPolicy</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Can we do it in postman? I am not able to produce the HTTP request body. Could you please help me?

Comment: I was able to retrieve this using workbench. but I cannot see the password policy settings for each profile.